# How to pass a global variable to multiple functions in multiple files

Tags: javascript, dom-events, global-variables

```
<script> 
var word = new Array(); word[1] = 'new'; word[2] = 'old';
</script> 

<script src="javascript/validator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And, in the validator.js we have:

```
function validate(number){ 
  alert(word[number]);
}
```

How to catch the variable value?
I always get an error saying the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Probably not a great idea to name your function alert since alert already exists.  Is your call to `alert` inside of your `alert` function supposed to be recursive or is it supposed to call the built in `alert`?

Comment: I don't think your alert function is meant to be recursive... other than that, your code should work fine.

Comment: 1) You overwrite the `alert` function. 2) An array starts at 0.

Comment: ok, my bad... sorry... this is only a small example. the function is not named 'alert' ... actually, this var will be used in serveal functions.
Just to make clear, is multilanguage system, based in a mysql DB...

It was working fine here in my computer using the <?= $dic->word['old'];?> inside the JS file... but, in the webserver, it doesn't work, so, I'm trying to find another way ....

Comment: error old version : http://agenciadefreela.com.br/badkamer/javascript/bk.php

Comment: @pimvdb Always an array will start with 0 ? can't i do like this: var arr = new arry; arr['color'] = 'red'; ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it.

This is the way I managed my multi-language message:

First I defined the array at the top of the page; as close as possible to the HEAD tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var resx = {};
</script>
```

Then, I fill the array with the values, using whatever method you use to get it from the database. In this example I use ASP.NET MVC.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     resx["word1"] = '@Model.word1';    
     resx["word2"] = '@Model.word2';    
     //or you can fill it directly
     resx["word3"] = 'Name';
     resx["word4"] = 'Nombre';
</script>
<script src="javascript/validator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then you use the way you want in the js file:

```
validate(“word2”);
function validate(value){ 
   alert(resx[value]);
}

//Or:
alert(resx[“word3”]);
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's probably not a good idea to be referencing globals across files. It can be confusing for other team members or maintainers to track them down. I would suggest always passing all necessary values to a function. This documents exactly what the function requires. Try this,

```
<script src="javascript/validator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var word = new Array('new', 'old');
validate(word, 0);
</script>
```

And in `validator.js`:

```
function validate(w, n){ 
    alert(w[n]);
}
```